# Cost of producing [not only] fitness equipment - does it have a home in SO family?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I've found out this closed question about the [cost of kettlebells](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/10243/why-are-kettlebells-so-expensive).

I find it an interesting question that certainly is answerable, because in such a competitive area like fitness equipment, if nobody produces something cheap, it is likely it can't be produced cheap (or, in some rare cases, like sleeping mattresses in Germany, we have a [Veblen market](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Veblen_good)).

Is there a site where questions about the cost aspects of producing things (both in small series or on large scale) would be on topic?

Comment: The closest I could think of might be [SE Economics](https://economics.stackexchange.com/), I though have zero experience with that site.

Comment: If you limited the question to just the relative casting cost versus a free weight Engineering.SE might be worth a try, I'd guess they need a bigger mould and more time to cool but I'm not sure cost-wise how significant that would be.